# Java Code not able to connect to solace message broker

Tags: solace

I have deployed solace message broker in my EKS cluster. I also deployed my java application in same EKS cluster. I have used internal service on top of 55555 port. My java application is not able to connect to this service. I am getting below exception.

```html
 07:26:14 [main]            ERROR c.s.m.MessagingServiceClientBuilder$BasicMessagingServiceImpl - MessagingServiceImpl@1 failed to connect and is disconnecting
com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException: (Client name: vva-74/38/00940001/PGJCsH4QQB   Local port: -1   Remote addr: solace-pubsub-standard-pubsubplus-smf  Remote port: 80) - Error communicating with the router.
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpChannel.executePostOnce(TcpChannel.java:254)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.ChannelOpStrategyClient.performOpen(ChannelOpStrategyClient.java:101)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.performOpenSingle(TcpClientChannel.java:428)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.access$800(TcpClientChannel.java:124)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel$ClientChannelConnect.call(TcpClientChannel.java:2610)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.open(TcpClientChannel.java:404)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPBasicSession.sniffRouter(JCSMPBasicSession.java:423)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPBasicSession.connect(JCSMPBasicSession.java:1310)
    at com.solace.messaging.util.internal.ClientSessionImpl.connect(ClientSessionImpl.java:388)
    at com.solace.messaging.MessagingServiceClientBuilder$BasicMessagingServiceImpl.onConnect(MessagingServiceClientBuilder.java:602)
    at com.solace.messaging.MessagingServiceClientBuilder$BasicMessagingServiceImpl.connectAsync(MessagingServiceClientBuilder.java:494)
    at com.solace.messaging.MessagingServiceClientBuilder$BasicMessagingServiceImpl.connect(MessagingServiceClientBuilder.java:398)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at java.base/java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.configureBlocking(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SimpleSmfClient.open(SimpleSmfClient.java:905)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SimpleSmfClient.doPostNoResponse(SimpleSmfClient.java:318)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SimpleSmfClient.doPost(SimpleSmfClient.java:235)
    at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpChannel.executePostOnce(TcpChannel.java:199)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Solace SMF service

```html
#Solace service accessible by producer and consumer
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: solace-pubsub-standard-pubsubplus-smf
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: pubsubplus-ha
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: solace-pubsub-standard
  annotations:
    service.alpha.kubernetes.io/tolerate-unready-endpoints: "true"
spec:
  ports:
  - name: tcp-smf
    port: 80
    targetPort: 55555
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: pubsubplus-ha
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: solace-pubsub-standard
  publishNotReadyAddresses: true
---
```

In my java application , I am using solace.messaging.transport.host = tcp://solace-pubsub-standard-pubsubplus-smf:80

Note: From python application running in different pod, I am able to connect this service

Can anyone please help me?